# vimL, how to get alternate window's current buffer number

Tags: vimscript, vim-windows, functions

Say, with 2 windows open in vim, cursor is window 2, how can I get the current buffer of the alternate window (window 1 in this case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
" current window buffer number
:echo winbufnr(winnr())

" 'previous' window buffer number
:echo winbufnr(winnr('#'))

" Name of the 'previous' window buffer number
:echo bufname(winbufnr(winnr('#')))
```

"Previous" here means the window you have switched from to the current with, for example, `<C-w>w`. So if you have 3+ windows opened then the last command will show you buffer name of the window you were in "previously" :)

To make it more "generic" you can try to play with `winnr()` function and friends.

Comment: Thx, with help the this answer, I solved the problem.